# Paypal Pay Now Button with language support

Tags: php, html, paypal

When the user click on the paypal pay button in my site, it will redirect to paypal payment page, which require the user to enter their paypal credentials. Currently, the paypal payment page is in english. I want it to be in Spanish or other language based on my site language. Below is the post data that i send to paypal.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal['merchant_account']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $paypal['webpage_url'].$language_path.$paypal['return_url']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $currency; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $itemName; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo number_format((float) $order->getTotal(), 2, '.', ''); ?>">
```

i tried to do something like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="es_es">
```

But it does not work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `lc=es_es`

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="vimaluk@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="es_es">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thanks. It works but when i enter my username and password and press "Entrar", the next page in paypal is back to english. Do you know how can I make it in spanish throughout the whole transaction process for paypal?